# ggplot: Generate a sequence of histograms

Tags: r, ggplot2

Say I have a `data.table` that contains observations over two dimensions, a time and a group identifier. (Sample data at the end)

I can get the histogram for any year using

```
ggplot(matches[year = someYear], aes(x=length)) + geom_bar()
```

But how could I generate a subplot for every year? Do I need to loop over every year, or is there some more convenient way?

Sample data:

```
    year length NOBS
 1: 1993      1   69
 2: 1993      2   31
 3: 1993      3   26
 4: 1993      4   16
 5: 1993      5   16
 6: 1993      6   14
 7: 1993      7   11
 8: 1993      8    6
 9: 1993      9    5
10: 1993     10    6
11: 1993     11    3
12: 1993     12    1
13: 1993     13    1
14: 1993     14    4
15: 1993     18    7
16: 1994      1   24
17: 1994      2    2
18: 1994      3    3
19: 1994      4    2
20: 1994      5    3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
ggplot(mydf, aes(x=length, y=NOBS))+geom_bar(stat='identity')+facet_grid(~year)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [facets](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Facets_%28ggplot2%29/), check: `?facet_grid`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice `multiplot` function at [cookbook-r](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/) that accepts a list of `ggplots`.  You can click on the link to get the code.  As such, you can simply loop over your years and store the plots in a list to plot.

```
plots <- list()
years <- unique(matches$year)
for(i in 1:length(unique(matches$year))){
  plots[[i]] <- ggplot(matches[which(matches$year==years[i]),], aes(x=length)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=1)
}

multiplot(plotlist=plots)
```